# How to free allocated GiB memory in EC2 CUDA GPU instance

Tags: gpu, pytorch

I have a `p3.2xlarge` instance, I ran a couple of experiments on the instance, and now that I want to run a new experiment (deep learning) I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 64.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.78 GiB total capacity; 14.70 GiB already allocated; 34.44 MiB free; 14.76 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

I wonder if there's any way that I can free the allocated memories so that I can run my experiment? Is freeing the memories even the solution for such an error?

Comment: end all of your python/pytorch sessions.  If that doesn't work, reboot the instance.

Comment: @RobertCrovella after rebooting the instance and even stopping and restarting it, I still get the same error.

Comment: Then you are running out of memory.  Whatever you are doing in pytorch "new experiment" apparently requires more memory than your GPU has.

Comment: if you're leaking memory to your GPU for some reason you could free GPU cache using `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` but if your trying to do something that needs more GPU memory than you have available theirs not much you can do. It would be worth checking the used memory before running with `nvidia-smi` (assuming unix system) to see the memory currently allocated to that memory.